# How to access Twitter Account Followers into iphone using iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get twitter Follower in IOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495998/get-twitter-follower-in-ios-5)

How to access Twitter Account Followers into iphone using iOS5?
I am new to iOS5 , can u please suggest with some code or links.

Thanks in Advance
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS5 twitter is intregated.... then No Use Extra frameWork...
try this code

```
- (void)OnTwitter {
        Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

            if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass != nil) {
                if([TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendTweet)]) {
                    UIViewController *twitterViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass alloc] init];

                    [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(setInitialText:) 
                                                withObject:twitterText];
                    [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(addURL:) 
                                                withObject:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

                    [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(addImage:) 
                                                withObject:urImage];
                    [self presentModalViewController:twitterViewController animated:YES];
                    [twitterViewController release];
                }
        else {
        // Use ShareKit for previous versions of iOS
        } 

    }
```

import the  farmeWork in your Class

```
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
 #import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [link to find how to access twitter accounts](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/ios-5-twitter-framework-part-2.html)
 Then you can easily use the API to find the followers